# How can I check if a XHR is made with HTTP/2.0?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, http2

How can I check if a XMLHttpRequest is made with HTTP/2.0? At the moment I'm doing the following, but of course that only works in Firefox.

```
if (req.getResponseHeader('X-Firefox-Spdy')) {
  if (req.getResponseHeader('X-Firefox-Spdy').startsWith('h2')) {
    return true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the status line is excluded of the string returned by [`getAllResponseHeaders`](https://w3c.github.io/XMLHttpRequest/Overview.html#dom-xmlhttprequest-getallresponseheaders) and [HTTP/2 does not define a way to carry the version … that is included in an HTTP/1.1 status line](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/#HttpResponse) you shouldn't be able to detect the version in a reliable way.

Nonetheless some versions of certain browsers—notably Safari 10—do carry the version by appending `HTTP/2.0` before the reason phrase of the `statusText` property.

```
if (req.statusText.startsWith('HTTP/2.0 '))
  // HTTP/2.0 enabled
else
  // we don't know either way
```